# How to convert JSON subelement strings to real JSON elements in bash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, cassandra, posix, jq

I have JSON message exported from Cassandra which I would like to load into Elastic as structured document:

```
{
  "correlationId": "fb8f855a0eac8985d430896d",
  "leg": 65535,
  "tag": "circuitpath",
  "offset": 479306,
  "len": 508,
  "prev": {
    "page": {
      "file": 10342,
      "page": 8
    },
    "record": 216
  },
  "data": "[ { \"policy\": \"Health Check\", \"execTime\": 0, \"filters\": [  { \"espk\": \"DEFAULT_PRIMARY_VordelGateway_7.4.0:223\", \"name\": \"Set Message\", \"type\": \"ChangeMessageFilter\", \"class\": \"com.vordel.circuit.conversion.ChangeMessageFilter\", \"status\": \"Pass\", \"filterTime\": 1518702587006, \"execTime\": 0 } , { \"espk\": \"DEFAULT_PRIMARY_VordelGateway_7.4.0:222\", \"name\": \"Reflect\", \"type\": \"ReflectFilter\", \"class\": \"com.vordel.circuit.net.ReflectFilter\", \"status\": \"Pass\", \"filterTime\": 1518702587006, \"execTime\": 0 }  ] } ]"
}
```

But I do not know how by simply way I could convert the "data" content to format which will allow to load it into Elastic.

I have tried following method where $json is the message above:

```
json2="${json//\\\"/\"}"
json2="${json2//\\\\/\\}"
echo "$json2"
```

the "data" element then seems like:

```
"data":"[ { "policy": "Health Check", "execTime": 0, "filters": [ { "espk": "DEFAULT_PRIMARY_VordelGateway_7.4.0:223", "name": "Set Message", "type": "ChangeMessageFilter", "class": "com.vordel.circuit.conversion.ChangeMessageFilter", "status": "Pass", "filterTime": 1518709297006, "execTime": 0 } , { "espk": "DEFAULT_PRIMARY_VordelGateway_7.4.0:222", "name": "Reflect", "type": "ReflectFilter", "class": "com.vordel.circuit.net.ReflectFilter", "status": "Pass", "filterTime": 1518709297006, "execTime": 0 } ] } ]"
```

but loader is telling me

> "status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed
>   to
>   parse","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected
>   character ('p' (code 112)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT
>   entries\n at [Source:
>   org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@3508edee;
>   line: 1, column: 170

It seems like it has problem with letter "p" in the first sub-sub-element name "policy"

Any idea how to get it into Elastic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the .data element from a JSON string into a JSON object, you could use the filter:

```
.data |= fromjson
```

If you just want to extract the .data element and convert it, you could use the filter:

```
.data | fromjson
```

For example: `jq -c '.data|fromjson' data.json`

#### Supplemental question

If it is uncertain whether or not `fromjson` will succeed, you could use the idiom: `fromjson? // .`, e.g.:

```
.data |= (fromjson? // .)
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is valid JSON, you probably need to parse the `data` element of the object.

If you would accept python:

1. write to a file, say `record.json` (for convenience, you can as well use stdin)
2. python (replace file names or use sys.stdin and sys.stdout)

   ```
   import json
   record = json.load(open('/path/to/record.json'))
   data = json.loads(record['data'])
   record['data'] = data
   json.dump(record, open("/path/to/result.json", "w"))
   ```